# Is Racket expt using tail recursion?

Tags: loops, lisp, racket, tail-recursion

If I try this in Racket:

```
(expt 2 1000)
```

I get a number many times bigger than all the atoms in the universe:

```
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

I can even get crazier with `(expt 2 10000)` which still only takes a second on my T450 laptop. So as I understand, this is only possible because of tail recursion. Is this correct? If so, is Racket's tail recursion pure functional programming, or are there hidden side-effects going on behind the scenes? Also, when I see Common Lisp's `loop`, is it based on tail recursion under the hood? In general, I guess I'm wondering how these feats of recursion/looping are possible.

Comment: “So as I understand, this is only possible because of tail recursion. Is this correct?” No.

Comment: @Alexis King: Elaborate, please. . . .

Comment: @147pm linear (in magnitude) algorithm means it is exponential in number of digits. smart algorithm is much more important, like say repeated squaring.

Comment: I found the implementation of `expt` [here](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/f4c48dd9b5b415e84d879caa98b44a439b3fb65f/racket/src/racket/src/number.c#L3572-L3742), which is in the C code, so probably isn’t doing anything with tail calls.

Answer (score 6):

Racket uses a C library to implement large integers (bignums).
The library is called GMP:

https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html

Now the case of 2^n is pretty easy to implement in a binary represetation.
You only need a 1 followed by n zeros. That is, GMP can compute the number very fast.

Comment: Yeah - let's not talk about that.

Comment: Okay. :) (can't help myself. I suspect 2 to 10 shouldn't be a problem and only conversions between coprime bases are hard).

Comment: All right, so is this what is going on behind the scenes with, say, Haskell too? `2**1000` is handed off to GMP or some C library?

Comment: Depends on the compiler. GHC uses GMP. https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Design/IntegerGmp2

Answer (score 3):

Tail calling is a wonderful thing, but it's important to understand that it doesn't make it possible to compute things that wouldn't be computable otherwise. In general, any code that's written in (say) a functional language with tail-calling can be written in another language using a loop. The advantage of a language with tail-calling is that programmers don't need to rewrite their recursive calls to loops in order to allow their programs to run.

It looks like you're focusing here on the ability of Racket (and Scheme) to compute with very large numbers. This is because, by default, Racket and Scheme use "bignums" to represent integers. Packages with bignum functionality are available for many languages, including C, but they can make for extra work in languages without garbage collection, because their representations are not of a bounded size.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, when I see Common Lisp's loop, is it based on tail recursion under the hood?

This is an implementation detail, but most likely not. First, CL already allows `TAGBODY` blocks, which makes `LOOP` expressible in terms of CL constructs.

For example, if I macroexpand a simple LOOP:

```
(loop)
```

I obtain a rather uniform result across implementations.

```
;; SBCL
(BLOCK NIL (TAGBODY #:G869 (PROGN) (GO #:G869)))

;; CCL
(BLOCK NIL (TAGBODY #:G4 (PROGN) (GO #:G4)))

;; JSCL
(BLOCK NIL (TAGBODY #:G869 (PROGN) (GO #:G869)))

;; ECL
(BLOCK NIL (TAGBODY #:G109 (PROGN) (GO #:G109)))

;; ABCL
(BLOCK NIL (TAGBODY #:G44 (GO #:G44)))
```

Implementation are typically written in languages that have jump or loops, or that can emulate them easily. Moreover, a lot of CL implementations are compiled and can target assembly language that has jump primitives. So usually, there is no need to have an intermediate step that goes through tail-recursive functions.

That being said, implementing `TAGBODY` with tail-recursion seems doable.
For example JSCL cuts the expressions inside a `tagbody` into different methods, for each label, and those methods are called when using `go`: https://github.com/jscl-project/jscl/blob/db07c5ebfa2e254a0154666465d6f7591ce66e37/src/compiler/compiler.lisp#L982

Moreover, if I let the `loop` run for a while, no stack overflow happen. In that case however this is not due to tail-call elimination (which, AFAIK, is not implemented on all browsers). It looks like the code for `tagbody` always has an implicit `while` loop, and that `go` throws exceptions for the `tagbody` to catch.